# Getting problem while uploading multiple images for a specific user in a nested array and converting it into binary

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, postgresql, multer

`InstructorLicenseDetails` is a nested array name in which each object contains a `LicenseImage` with file details. I am unable to send binary in formData like below in multer.

This is how I am sending from frontend, it only receives `ProfileImage` and `TRainerPermitImage`.

```js
const InstructorFormData = new FormData();
    let InstructorDataNoImage = {};
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(InstructorData)) {
    console.log("key:", key, "value:", value);
    if (key.indexOf("Image") > -1) {
       InstructorFormData.append(key, value);
    } else
          InstructorDataNoImage = { ...InstructorDataNoImage, [key]: value };
    }



export const MulterFor_InstructorImages = (req, res, next) =\> {
    console.log("MulterFor_InstructorImages Reqbody", req.body);
    let MulterVals = {};

    MulterVals.filepath = "./Public/Institute/Instructors";
    MulterVals.UploadFields = [
        { name: "ProfileImage" },
    
        { name: "TrainerPermitImage" },
        ...(req.body.InstructorLicenseDetails || []).map((license, index) => ({
            name: `LicenseImage_${index + 1}`,
        })),
        ...(req.body.SpecialLicenseDetails || []).map((license, index) => ({
            name: `SLicenseImage_${index + 1}`,
        })),
    ];
    MulterVals.filetypes = [];
    MulterVals.filetypes[0] = "image/png";
    MulterVals.filetypes[1] = "image/jpg";
    MulterVals.filetypes[2] = "image/jpeg";
    MulterVals.filetypes[3] = "image/svg+xml";
    MulterMiddleware(req, res, next, MulterVals);

};
```

Now, how to send nested array images with a dynamic field name as given in multer?